# Finding Active Record Associations in Rails Using SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server

New to Rails and SQL and I'm trying to access associations in my app.

I have an itinerary web app where users can come and download itineraries. As part of the process they can leave reviews with their thoughts. I want the owner of the review to be able to edit or delete her review after the thought if need be, but the following Active Record Association is returning an error for @itinerary.reviews.user_id:

```
undefined method `user_id' for #<Review::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fb969392978>
```

Inside my itineraries_helper:

```
 def user_is_reviewer?
  @itinerary = Itinerary.find(params[:id])
  !!current_user.id == @itinerary.reviews.user_id
end
```

In my view:

```
<div class = "review-container">
    <h2>What Travelers Thought</h2>
    <% if @itinerary.reviews.count > 0 %>
    <% @itinerary.reviews.each do |review| %>
    <div class = "reviews">

      <div class = "star-rating" data-score= <%= review.rating %> ></div>
      <p>
        <%= review.comment %>
      </p>
      <% if  user_is_reviewer? %>
      <% link_to "Edit", edit_itinerary_review_path(@itinerary, @review) %>
      <% end %>

    <% end %>
   </div>
```

Questions:

1. Why does Review.first.user_id work but not itineraries.reviews.user_id
2. What SQL command will achieve what I am looking for?
3. If I can use SQL, what SQL resource can I pick up to learn more? If not, whats a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Review.first` will return your a Review Object and you are accessing the user_id associated with it by `Review.first.user_id`

while

```
itinerary.reviews
```

is returning a collection of all the reviews that belongs to a particular itinerary and it is collection of active record objects and you were trying to access the user_id from active record collection which is not going to work.

You can solve it by passing review id to your helper method

```
def user_is_reviewer?(review_id)
  review = Review.find(review_id)
 !!current_user.id == review.user_id
end
```

In your view updating the helper method to have review id passed

```
<% if  user_is_reviewer?(review) %>
  <% link_to "Edit", edit_itinerary_review_path(@itinerary, @review) %>
<% end %>
```

OR else you can simply go without a helper method as you already have a review object like following in your view

```
<% if current_user.id == review.user_id %>
  <% link_to "Edit", edit_itinerary_review_path(@itinerary, @review) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow - thanks for such a clear explanation Shani. Just to clarify, collections is an array, so you cant access one particular id from it? What if I did itinerary.reviews.first.user_id?

Comment: collection is an array of objects. you can iterate through on array  to access individual object attributes. You were trying to access user_id on a collection of an array. hope that helps